# DAO generator for java

Tags: java, dao

I'm searching for free and simple DAO generator for java (it needs to create entities/bens from db tables/views and generate basic CRUD code). Currently, I`m using DAO4J which lacks some functionality like views mapping. I know that there are frameworks like Hibernate but I dont need such robust framework.

Some things this framework should have to do:

- Generate CRUD operations with standard SQL queries and not compile-time typesafe queries
- Doesn't have session concept like hibernate
- Will not automatically close connection
- JDBC Connection can be configured through code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of these are perfect matches, but both rock, in their own individual way:

1. [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) generates DAOs, Web
   Controllers and more for you.
2. [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) automatically [creates Objects from your database tables](http://blog.mysema.com/2011/01/querying-in-sql-with-querydsl.html) and offers an Object-Oriented query syntax with compile-time safety.

But I'd say the winner is [Spring Data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data). It offers a simple but powerful abstraction over many different underlying data store technologies and generates daos for you automatically. Here's a presentation of [Spring Data JPA](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa). <s>Unfortunately Spring Data has not been released in final versions yet.</s>

Comment: DeltaSpike (https://deltaspike.apache.org/) is an alternative by Apache, and a quick walk through can be seen at https://jaxenter.com/top-3-jpa-productivity-boosters-for-java-ee-developers-deltaspike-data-116136.html

Comment: @user3257644 I'd suggest you write that as an additional answer

Answer (score 7):

If you just need a code generator without adherence to a framework, you should try **Telosys Tools**. It's a lightweight tool, it generates code from an existing database model.

See https://www.telosys.org

Some templates are specially designed for **JDBC code generation**, they are available on GitHub 
https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3

They offer code generation for DAO, DAO interfaces, POJO (beans), JUnit tests, etc

Answer (score 6):

To add to duffymo's answer, MyBatis is good and you can use the [MyBatis generator](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Generator) to generate data access code.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be much in favor of automatic generation.

I can recommend iBatis as a half step between JDBC and Hibernate.

Comment: The project has now changed to myBatis: http://www.mybatis.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Hibernate Tools](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.0.0.GA/hibernatetools/en/html_single/index.html). But I personally never tried it, I have only created entity classes by now.

Comment: The one thing I found with Hibernate, is that there can be a pretty steep learning curve once you get past the basic CRUD stuff. For me, the efficiency gains dropped pretty quickly once I got past initial prototyping. Sometimes it's easier just to use lead bullets. I now just use Spring JDBCTemplates. I think it provides a good mix of limiting boilerplate code while still allowing you to do complex queries.

Answer (score 2):

I would second iBatis. Other suggestion can be `Spring JDBCTemplate`. Since you are fine to adopt a framework, so why not go with `Spring`. It will also facilitate you with other great things.

Comment: I'm new to Java and my project is time limited so I can't waste time learning new big frameworks. I hope that I will one day use Spring framework ...

Comment: @Ivan: The brilliance of Spring lies in its distributions and use. It is as big as your use of it.

Comment: Can't agree more on that, but since I`m begginer in Java world its a bit hustle with all this new stuff.