# Is there any template to generate java code snippet for spring jdbc template

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am in need of Code generator DAO Implementation using Spring Jdbc Template.

Is there any generator (Similar to Hibernate) to generate the DAOImpl for a entity based on DB.

ie. if i give the db connection details(DB Details) so the Generator will generate Entity, Dao Impl class with basic CRUD operation and findby methos.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [DAO generator for java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042336/dao-generator-for-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at Spring roo. You can try Incremental Database Reverse Engineering.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/intro.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that with **Telosys** a simple code generator
http://www.telosys.org

Some templates are available on GitHub 
https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3